# DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.PutAttachment silently fails

Tags: c#, ravendb

Following the samples in the [RavenDB Attachment docs](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/attachments) and [RavenDB Attachments - Functionality how to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457533/ravendb-attachments-functionality-how-to-do), I'm trying to add attachments to a Raven instance with the following code:

```
foreach (var currentDoc in docsToStore) {
  byte[] buff = ReadBytesFromFile(currentDoc.FilePath);
  var attachmentId = "attachedpages/" + attachmentCounter;
  var stream = new MemoryStream(buff);

  documentStore.DatabaseCommands.PutAttachment(attachmentId, null, stream, null);
  currentDoc.Attachments.Add(attachmentId);
  session.Store(currentDoc);  //Add the new document to Raven
}
session.saveChanges();
```

I've looked in the debugger to confirm that the MemoryStream has the data I expect.  I also see the reference to currentDoc in the management studio.  However, `http://localhost:8080/static/?start=0&pagesize=128` simply returns an empty array.

Is there another step I need to take in order to save attachments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `http://localhost:8080/static/?start=0&pagesize=128` wasn't showing my attachments.  When I looked for them with either:

```
documentStore.DatabaseCommands.GetAttachmentHeadersStartingWith("", 0, 128);

documentStore.DatabaseCommands.ForDatabase("Mydb")
    .GetAttachmentHeadersStartingWith("", 0, 128);
```

Then I saw all the attachments I'd been trying to save.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `documentStore.DatabaseCommands` will return a db commands for the *default* database.

You probably need to do:

```
documentStore.DatabaseCommands.ForDatabase("Mydb").PutAttachment
```