# Generate unique string for Lucky number

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unique random string generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730268/unique-random-string-generation)

I have to generate a random unique string. The purpose of this is to generate a **Lucky Number** after every successful entry in a table.

I dont like to use GUID, since it is as dash(-) in between.
[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730268/unique-random-string-generation) but it also seems too long.

I would like to generate a string which has around 10 chars.

Any good ideas would be much much appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Yes I could do that..but still it is too long for this purpose.

Comment: "seems too long" is hardly a reason to post another question.

Comment: Is this something? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122483/c-sharp-random-string-generator

Comment: How is the "uniqueness" measured? Does it have to be unique just for one run of the program? Or for all runs on one machine? Or for all runs on all machines in the world? More context is needed!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a string representation of a Guid without the dashes:

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
```

Granted, it is 32 characters long, not 10. But it is a simple and fast solution.

Comment: They are of course very boring hex numbers. And 3.2 times too long, even more boring.

Comment: Sometimes "boring" is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
public struct ShortGuid
{
    private Guid _underlyingGuid;

    public ShortGuid(Guid underlyingGuid) : this()
    {
        _underlyingGuid = underlyingGuid;
    }

    public static ShortGuid Empty 
    {
        get { return ConvertGuidToShortGuid(Guid.Empty); }
    }

    public static ShortGuid NewShortGuid()
    {
        return ConvertGuidToShortGuid(Guid.NewGuid());
    }

    private static ShortGuid ConvertGuidToShortGuid(Guid guid)
    {
        return new ShortGuid(guid);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(_underlyingGuid.ToByteArray()).EscapeNonCharAndNonDigitSymbols();
    }

    public bool Equals(ShortGuid other)
    {
        return other._underlyingGuid.Equals(_underlyingGuid);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof (ShortGuid)) return false;
        return Equals((ShortGuid) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _underlyingGuid.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

where **EscapeNonCharAndNonDigitSymbols** is an extension method:

```
    public static string EscapeNonCharAndNonDigitSymbols(this string str)
    {
        if (str == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        var chars = new List<char>(str.ToCharArray());

        for (int i = str.Length-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            if (!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(chars[i]))
                chars.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        return new String(chars.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: This one will give you 18 characters like: 0ULpP0HECPquj8TtGA

Answer (score 0):

Just yesterday had to do the same task. Here you go:

```
public static class RandomStringService
{
    //Generate new random every time used. Must sit outside of the function, as static, otherwise there would be no randomness.
    private static readonly Random Rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);


    /// <summary>
    /// Create random unique string- checking against a table
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Random string of defined length</returns>
    public static String GenerateUniqueRandomString(int length)
    {
        //check if the string is unique in Barcode table.
        String newCode;
        do
        {
            newCode = GenerateRandomString(length);

         // and check if there is no duplicates, regenerate the code again.
        } while (_tableRepository.AllRecords.Any(l => l.UniqueString == newCode));

//In my case _tableRepository is injected via DI container and represents a proxy for 
//EntityFramework context. This step is not really necessary, most of the times you can use 
//method below: GenerateRandomString

        return newCode;
    }




    /// <summary>
    /// Generates the random string of given length.
    /// String consists of uppercase letters only.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="size">The required length of the string.</param>
    /// <returns>String</returns>
    private static string GenerateRandomString(int size)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        char ch;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            ch = Convert.ToChar(CreateRandomIntForString());
            builder.Append(ch);
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Create a random number corresponding to ASCII uppercase or a digit
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Integer between 48-57 or between 65-90</returns>
    private static int CreateRandomIntForString()
    {
        //ASCII codes
        //48-57 = digits
        //65-90 = Uppercase letters
        //97-122 = lowercase letters

        int i;
        do
        {
            i = Convert.ToInt32(Rand.Next(48, 90));
        } while (i > 57 && i < 65);

        return i;
    }
```

Comment: mm? explain please. Do you mean, it can be done with less key-strokes? Sure it can be, no doubt in that.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace LinqRandomString
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            do
            {
                byte[] random = new byte[10000];

                using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
                    rng.GetBytes(random);


                var q = random
                            .Where(i => (i >= 65 && i <= 90) || (i >= 97 && i <= 122)) // ascii ranges - change to include symbols etc
                            .Take(10) // first 10
                            .Select(i => Convert.ToChar(i)); // convert to a character

                foreach (var c in q)
                    Console.Write(c);

            } while (Console.ReadLine() != "exit");
        }
    }
}
```