# Unique string for each record in the database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

In my Asp.Net MVC 5 project I use Entity Framework code first to work with MS SQL database. Suppose this is the table:

```
public class Ticket
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ReferenceCode { get; set; }

    //Rest of the table
}
```

In this table, whenever I add a new code I want the `ReferenceCode` column to be a **unique** and random AlphaNumeric (containing only letters and digits) string with a specific length. This will allow users to refer to a specific ticket for instance.

These are some examples with 10 character lenght: `TK254X26W1`, `W2S564Z111`, `1STT135PA5`...

Right now, I'm able to generate random strings with the given length. However, I'm not sure how to guarantee their *uniqueness*. I do it like this:

```
db.Tickets.Add(new Ticket()
{
   ReferenceCode = GenerateRandomCode(10),
   //...
});
```

To be exact, I want the `GenerateRandomCode` function or maybe another method to be able to make sure the generated string has not been used for another record.

I can use a `for` loop to check each generated code but I don't think it's a good idea. Especially after a while when the table will have thousands of records.

Comment: This question is far too broad (you should know this by now considering you have over 6k rep.)

Comment: @DavidG Well I thought it was specific enough but sure I'll edit.

Comment: Why not just use Ticket.Id for that?

Comment: @Evk based on project needs I need the string as well. Something like a `username` and `user.Id`. They're different but both are needed.

Comment: Do you really need that string to be random? Because you can convert your Ticket.Id into 10 character string, and back, if the only thing you need is a "good looking" reference number.

Comment: @Evk unfortunately yes. The users shouldn't be able to guess the code. It's basically there to confirm that the user has seen the ticket.

Comment: What if user cannot guess it unless he knows the algorithm with which it was generated (so basically has access to your codebase)?

Comment: @Evk I'm not exactly sure but I think the chance of getting a duplicated and the user having access to that record is far less than being able to reverse-engineer the algorithm for generating the codes. In that case isn't it better to just use a random code? What do you think?

Comment: Well if that was a code to protect some financial transaction and there was financial risk if users could guess id from code - then I would agree it's of course better to use random strings (cryptographically random). But in this case there seems to be absolutely no reason for users to try to reverse engineer anything, why? I used deterministic strings for similar purposes (where I did not want to expose id directly and wanted a nice-looking string) and I think it's fine.

Comment: All in all, if you want random string - just put unique index on ReferenceCode, generate it, insert, and catch unique index violation error (which will be super rare of course). If caught - generate new string and insert again.

Comment: The total number of unique strings of 10 alphanumeric characters is `36 ^ 10` - that's a huge number - `3,656,158,440,062,976` if you want to be exact. The chance of generating a string that's already in your table, if you only have a few thousend rows, and even if you have 1,000,000 records, is extreamly low.  
Therefor, I agree with @Evk's last statement - it's safe and simple to just add a unique constraint (or index) on ReferenceCode and wrap the inserts and updates in a try catch.

Comment: *It's basically there to confirm that the user has seen the ticket* Does it even matter when they're not unique? What's the chance that a user inadvertently produces the right ticket code for someone else's ticket? Even check numbers for internet banking transactions (6 digits in my case) aren't unique.

Comment: To generate random no use the code.          private static Random random = new Random();
        public static string RandomString(int length)
        {
            const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
              .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
        }

Comment: If you want to add only if same Reference no. is not present, then you need do do two thing : 1) Add Unique Key Constrain to the Column ReferenceNo for the table 2) Create a stored procedure to add "if not exist" that referenceCode(you generated from your code) query. That's it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my approach that guarantees uniqueness and introduces some randomness.

1. Use a **sequence generator that is guaranteed to give a unique number**. Since you're working with SQL Server, this can be an `IDENTITY` column's value. You could alternatively increment an application-level value within your C# code to achieve this.
2. Generate a **random integer to bring in some randomness** to the result. This could be done with `Random.Next()` and any seed, even the number generated in the preceding step.
3. Use a method `EncodeInt32AsString` to convert the integers from the previous two steps into two strings (one is the *unique string*, one the *random string*). The method returns a string composed of only the allowed characters specified in the method. The logic of this method is similar to how **number conversion between different bases** takes place (for example, change the allowed string to only 0-9, or only 0-9A-F to get the decimal/hex representations). Therefore, the result is a "number" composed of the "digits" in `allowedList`.
4. **Concatenate the strings returned**. Keep the entire *unique string* as-is (to guarantee uniqueness) and add as many characters from the *random string* to pad the total length to the desired length. If required, this concatenation can be fancy, by injecting characters from the random string at random points into the unique string.

By retaining the entire unique string, this ensures uniqueness of the final result. 
By using a random string, this introduces randomness. Randomness cannot be guaranteed in case the target string's length is very close to the length of the unique string.

In my testing, calling `EncodeInt32AsString` for `Int32.MaxValue` returns a unique string 6 characters long:

> 2147483647: ZIK0ZJ

On that basis, a target string length of 12 will be ideal, though 10 is also reasonable.

**The `EncodeInt32AsString` Method**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Encodes the 'input' parameter into a string of characters defined by the allowed list (0-9, A-Z) 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">Integer that is to be encoded as a string</param>
    /// <param name="maxLength">If zero, the string is returned as-is. If non-zero, the string is truncated to this length</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static String EncodeInt32AsString(Int32 input, Int32 maxLength = 0)
    {
        // List of characters allowed in the target string 
        Char[] allowedList = new Char[] {
            '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
            'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
            'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
            'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
        Int32 allowedSize = allowedList.Length;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(input.ToString().Length);

        Int32 moduloResult;
        while (input > 0)
        {
            moduloResult = input % allowedSize;
            input /= allowedSize;
            result.Insert(0, allowedList[moduloResult]);
        }

        if (maxLength > result.Length)
        {
            result.Insert(0, new String(allowedList[0], maxLength - result.Length));
        }

        if (maxLength > 0)
            return result.ToString().Substring(0, maxLength);
        else
            return result.ToString();
    }
```

**The `GetRandomizedString` Method**

Now, the preceding method just takes care of encoding a string. In order to achieve the uniqueness and randomness properties, the following logic (or similar) can be used.

In the comments, Kevin pointed out the following risk with the implementation of the `EncodeInt32AsString` method:

> The code needs to be tweaked so that it returns a fixed-length string.
>   Otherwise, you can never be guaranteed of the final result is unique.
>   If it helps, picture one value generating ABCDE (Unique) +
>   F8CV1 (Random)... and then later on, another value generating
>   ABCDEF (Unique) + 8CV1 (Random). Both values are ABCDEF8CV1

This is a very valid point, and this has been addressed in the following `GetRandomizedString` method, by specifying lengths for the unique and random strings. The `EncodeInt32AsString` method has also been modified to pad out the return value to a specified length.

```
    // Returns a string that is the encoded representation of the input number, and a random value 
    static String GetRandomizedString(Int32 input)
    {
        Int32 uniqueLength = 6; // Length of the unique string (based on the input) 
        Int32 randomLength = 4; // Length of the random string (based on the RNG) 
        String uniqueString;
        String randomString;
        StringBuilder resultString = new StringBuilder(uniqueLength + randomLength);

        // This might not be the best way of seeding the RNG, so feel free to replace it with better alternatives. 
        // Here, the seed is based on the ratio of the current time and the input number. The ratio is flipped 
        // around (i.e. it is either M/N or N/M) to ensure an integer is returned. 
        // Casting an expression with Ticks (Long) to Int32 results in truncation, which is fine since this is 
        // only a seed for an RNG 
        Random randomizer = new Random(
                (Int32)(
                    DateTime.Now.Ticks + (DateTime.Now.Ticks > input ? DateTime.Now.Ticks / (input + 1) : input / DateTime.Now.Ticks)
                )
            );

        // Get a random number and encode it as a string, limit its length to 'randomLength' 
        randomString = EncodeInt32AsString(randomizer.Next(1, Int32.MaxValue), randomLength); 
        // Encode the input number and limit its length to 'uniqueLength' 
        uniqueString = EncodeInt32AsString(input, uniqueLength);

        // For debugging/display purposes alone: show the 2 constituent parts 
        resultString.AppendFormat("{0}\t {1}\t ", uniqueString, randomString);

        // Take successive characters from the unique and random strings and 
        // alternate them in the output 
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < Math.Min(uniqueLength, randomLength); i++)
        {
            resultString.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", uniqueString[i], randomString[i]);
        }
        resultString.Append((uniqueLength < randomLength ? randomString : uniqueString).Substring(Math.Min(uniqueLength, randomLength)));

        return resultString.ToString();
    }
```

**Sample Output**

Calling the above method for a variety of input values results in:

```
   Input Int     Unique String  Random String       Combined String 
------------ ----------------- -------------- --------------------- 
         -10            000000           CRJM            0C0R0J0M00
           0            000000           33VT            03030V0T00
           1            000001           DEQK            0D0E0Q0K01
        2147            0001NN           6IU8            060I0U18NN
       21474            000GKI           VNOA            0V0N0OGAKI
      214748            004LP8           REVP            0R0E4VLPP8
     2147483            01A10B           RPUM            0R1PAU1M0B
    21474836            0CSA38           RNL5            0RCNSLA538
   214748364            3JUSWC           EP3U            3EJPU3SUWC
  2147483647            ZIK0ZJ           BM2X            ZBIMK20XZJ
           1            000001           QTAF            0Q0T0A0F01
           2            000002           GTDT            0G0T0D0T02
           3            000003           YMEA            0Y0M0E0A03
           4            000004           P2EK            0P020E0K04
           5            000005           17CT            01070C0T05
           6            000006           WH12            0W0H010206
           7            000007           SHP0            0S0H0P0007
           8            000008           DDNM            0D0D0N0M08
           9            000009           192O            0109020O09
          10            00000A           KOLD            0K0O0L0D0A
          11            00000B           YUIN            0Y0U0I0N0B
          12            00000C           D8IO            0D080I0O0C
          13            00000D           KGB7            0K0G0B070D
          14            00000E           HROI            0H0R0O0I0E
          15            00000F           AGBT            0A0G0B0T0F
```

As can be seen above, the *unique string* is predictable for sequential numbers, given it is just the same number represented in a different base. However, the *random string* brings in some entropy to prevent users from guessing subsequent numbers. Moreover, by interleaving the "digits" of the *unique string* and *random string* it becomes slightly more difficult for users to observe any pattern.

In the above example, the length of the *unique string* is set to 6 (since that allows it to represent `Int32.MaxValue`), but the length of the *random string* is set to 4 because the OP wanted a total length of 10 characters.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your code I can modify my existing code to get the `Id` of the record and then return a unique string based on that. Plus I can set my own criteria. Awesome.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori - I'd made a small mistake in the contents of the `allowedList` array, which I've now corrected in the above answer. It doesn't change the overall answer itself.

Comment: The code needs to be tweaked so that it returns a fixed-length string.  Otherwise, you can never be guaranteed of the final result is unique.  If it helps, picture one value generating [ABCDE](Unique) + [F8CV1](Random)... and then later on, another value generating [ABCDEF](Unique) + [8CV1](Random).  Both values are ABCDEF8CV1.

Comment: Very nice catch, Kevin, thank you for pointing that out. I've modified the answer with a method `GetRandomizedString` that ensures that the unique and random strings are of specific lengths.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Guid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to generate unique (but not that random when it comes to security) keys.

Pulling from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730268/unique-random-string-generation):

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
string GuidString = Convert.ToBase64String(g.ToByteArray());
GuidString = GuidString.Replace("=","");
GuidString = GuidString.Replace("+","");
GuidString = GuidString.ToUpper();
```

will generate a unique key to fit your `ReferenceCode` property needs but longer (22 characters). Collapsing it and using a X characters would no longer guarantee its uniqueness.

> OZVV5TPP4U6XJTHACORZEQ

Answer (score 6):

Mind an off-the-beaten-path solution?  You've got two needs, that I can see:

- Randomness.  You can't have a "deterministic" function, because if someone can guess the algorithm, they could figure out everyone elses' ticket numbers.
- Uniqueness.  You can't have any duplicate ticket nums - which makes Random a bit difficult (you'll have to account for collisions and retry.)

But there's no reason you can't do both - you've got plenty of bit-space with 36^10.  You could dedicate 4 bytes to Uniqueness, and 6 bytes to Randomness.  Here's some sample code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

  private static Random random = new Random();
  private static int largeCoprimeNumber = 502277;
  private static int largestPossibleValue = 1679616;  // 36 ^ 4

  private static char[] Base36Alphabet = new char[] { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z' };

  public static string GetTicket(int id)
  {
    int adjustedID = id * largeCoprimeNumber % largestPossibleValue;
    string ticket = IntToString(adjustedID);
    while (ticket.Length < 4) ticket = "0" + ticket;
    return ticket + new string(Enumerable.Repeat(Base36Alphabet, 6) .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
  }

  private static string IntToString(int value)
  {
    string result = string.Empty;
    int targetBase = Base36Alphabet.Length;

    do
    {
        result = Base36Alphabet[value % targetBase] + result;
        value = value / targetBase;
    }
    while (value > 0);

    return result;
}
```

Quick rundown on what the code's doing.  You're passing in your int id - which it then hashes in such a way that it *looks* random, but is guaranteed to never repeat a number for the first 1.68 million entries.

It then takes this hashed int value, and turns it into a 4-digit code; this is the "uniqueness part" - you're guaranteed a different 4 digit code at the beginning of the first 1.68 million IDs (the magic of coprime numbers.)

That leaves 6 more characters to play with.  Just fill them in with random characters - that makes the whole 10-digit code awfully difficult to guess.

This solves both of your problems.  It's guaranteed to be unique for the first million+ records.  And it's not really "guessable" by the client, since even if they guessed the algorithm, they'd have 2 billion different possibilities for any given ID they wanted to crack.

Comment: Your approach is very similar to Phylyp's. However I went with that one because it was a little more flexible in terms of my needs. I'd happily give you the reps too but unfortunately the site won't let me. Thanks for taking the time to post your answer. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Eh, no worries.  But before you move on, make sure you resolve the fixed-length problem - because otherwise, you're going to have the same odds of generating a duplicate ticket as you would if you simply generated 10 random characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve absolute uniqueness on the machine using **UuidCreateSequential** method(which deals with Uuid) in **rpcrt4.dll** as below. Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379322(v=vs.85).aspx) from microsoft to be sure about uniqueness. You will never get the same Id twice on your machine or the host where you upload your website.

The output format from following code is what Asp.Net MVC uses to create unique id for AspNetUsers table:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class SqlGuidUtil
    {
        [DllImport("rpcrt4.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int UuidCreateSequential(out Guid guid);

        public static Guid NewSequentialId()
        {
            Guid guid;
            UuidCreateSequential(out guid);
            var s = guid.ToByteArray();
            var t = new byte[16];
            t[3] = s[0];
            t[2] = s[1];
            t[1] = s[2];
            t[0] = s[3];
            t[5] = s[4];
            t[4] = s[5];
            t[7] = s[6];
            t[6] = s[7];
            t[8] = s[8];
            t[9] = s[9];
            t[10] = s[10];
            t[11] = s[11];
            t[12] = s[12];
            t[13] = s[13];
            t[14] = s[14];
            t[15] = s[15];
            return new Guid(t);
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
Guid gid = SqlGuidUtil.NewSequentialId();
String sid = SqlGuidUtil.NewSequentialId().ToString();
```

Sample output:

> 637E3E78-23F5-E611-8278-506313F91120

This format is exactly the same as AspNet Identity user Id format.

You can also remove dashes(not a good idea) as below:

```
String sid = SqlGuidUtil.NewSequentialId().ToString().Replace("-","");
```

Comment: This is a nice approach however the string's length is too long. I might need strings with the length of 6 for instance.

Comment: Yes, you may not have control on the length. since you insisted on uniqueness, this is a windows feature and the fastest generator without looping. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Put a unique index on the DB column, and keep generating until the DB accepts it without a unique constraint. Collisions will be very rare.

Answer (score 1):

We needed to implement something like this for a different purpose in of our previous projects. We just pregenerated a number of unique identifiers into a new table (let's call it table A), and then when we wanted to insert a new record into table B, we just added the top 1 record from table A in a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

user your code like

```
string referenceCode=Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
referenceCode=referenceCode.Replace('-', '');
db.Tickets.Add(new Ticket()
{
   ReferenceCode = referenceCode;
   //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It's work for me

```
var buffer = new byte[5];
new Random().NextBytes(buffer);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", buffer.Select(b => b.ToString("X2"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your ID for granting uniqueness and the System.Random class to get you a randomness you may expect something like :

```
private string GenerateRandomCode(int Key)
{
    Random rnd = new Random(Key);
    char[] values = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".ToArray();

    string result = string.Empty;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
         result += values[rnd.Next(0, values.Length)];
    }

    return result;
}
```

The key value will ensure the same generated code and the random class has not enough period to worry about unicity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Substring(0, 10)
```

I used this while generating random strings for ID in SQL tables from C# codebase. This relies on randomness of C# Guid and everytime you will get a new alphanumeric String.

Answer (score 0):

Using Guid I have create a function to generate unique string. Of course GUIDs can collide, so I am altering the string in the middle with new Guid.

```
     static string GenerateRandomCode(){
        string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");     
        List<char> lst = new List<char>();
        int count = 1;

        foreach(char c in guid){                
            if(count==11) break;                
            if(count % 2 ==0){
                lst.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToCharArray()[1]);
            }
            else{
                lst.Add(c);
            }
            count++;
        }           
        return string.Join("",lst.ToArray());
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

Maybe this will help you

DECLARE @userReportId BIGINT

SET @userReportId = FLOOR(RAND()*(10000000000000-1) + 1);

Comment: This won't generate an alphanumeric string.

Comment: Play with that query :) change data type